# Tell Json this all one line

Tags: json

I am writing a JSON template for AWS SSM document.

Once of the commands I am trying to run looks like this:

```
"ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' <<< ""$'\n'"y" 2>&1 >/dev/null",
```

However, due to the "" after the <<< JSON thinks that this is a new line and is expecting a comma.

Is there a way I can tell JSON that that is a single command and need to be treated as a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes. So `"` inside your json string becomes `\"`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that sorted my issue!